# how to tackle HEX in torch7?

Tags: lua, torch

I'm using [async-tcp client](https://github.com/clementfarabet/async/blob/master/tests/test-tcp-client.lua) to connect to server and receive data(an array).

```
client.ondata(function(data)
   print('received:',data)
end)
```

If data type is HEX, I can get data but it is all gibberish.

It seems that there is something wrong with encoding.

---

If data type is note HEX, I can also get data but it is string.

I have no idea to convert the 'array string' to tensor.

'0.001 0.002 0.003' -> `torch.Tensor({{0.001, 0.002, 0.003}})`  ??

What should I do ?

Thank you

## ==================================================

EDIT

**string.byte**

```
client.ondata(function(data)
      print('received number:',#data)
      for i = 1, #data do
        print('received:', string.byte(data, i))
      end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the format ahead of time, you can use the `match` function to get the list of values from a string, which you can then convert to the table and the Tensor:

```
local str = "0.001 0.002 0.003"
torch.Tensor({{str:match("(%d+%.%d*)%s+(%d+%.%d*)%s+(%d+%.%d*)")}})
```

This returns:

```
0.001 *
  1.0000  2.0000  3.0000
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x3]
```

If the number is in the hex format, you can use `tonumber` function to convert, for example, `tonumber("0x12") == 18`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!